# How to use REST with MVC when there is no Database?

Tags: php, rest, model-view-controller

I have two servers, the first works using REST and other Webs pages that are built using MVC.

I usually always run *REST* commands in the Controller layer, however I am with a doubt, assuming that my project (using *MVC*) does not use database and I'm using *Controllers* only to send commands to the webservice to send and receive information.

- The *REST* this case would be the like *Model*?

  In this case I should call the Rest within the Controllers and not create Models. eg .:

  ```
  public function createProductAction() {
      $rest = Rest('ws.example.com', 'PUT /items/', array(
                                          'price' => $price,
                                          'description' => $descricao
                                      ));

      if ($response->status === 200) {
          View::show('success.tpl');
      } else {
          View::show('error.tpl', $rest->error());
      }
  }

  public function viewProductAction() {
      $rest = Rest('ws.example.com', 'GET /items/{id}', array(
                                          'id' => $_GET['id']
                                      ));

      $response = json_decode($rest->getRespose());

      if ($response->status() === 200) {
          View::show('product.tpl', $response);
      } else {
          View::show('error.tpl', $rest->error());
      }
  }
  ```

or

- I would have to create Models to make the calls to REST?

  For example:

  ```
  class ProductsModel
  {
      public function putItem($preco, $descricao)
      {
          $rest = Rest('ws.example.com', 'PUT /items/', array(
                                              'price' => $price,
                                              'description' => $descricao
                                          ));

          //If status=200 new product is added
          return $response->status() === 200;
      }

      public function deleteItem($id)
      {
          $rest = Rest('ws.example.com', 'DELETE /items/{id}', array(
                                              'id' => $id
                                          ));

          //If status=200 product is deleted
          return $rest->status() === 200;
      }

      public function getItem($id)
      {
          $rest = Rest('ws.example.com', 'GET /items/{id}', array(
                                              'id' => $id
                                          ));

          if ($rest->status() === 200) {
              //If status=200 return data
              return json_decode($rest->getRespose());
          }

          return NULL;
      }
  }
  ```

How should I proceed?

Comment: which MVC framework are you using? It would make sense if you create a RestModel which would separate data and logic.

Comment: @sabkaraja I am currently not using any framework, I just like to know when there is no database I must not create the *Models*. In the case it would be only the controllers and views, would it? Thanks

Comment: To use Model or not to is totally upto you. However, having Model will help in abstraction of logic and extend it easily:
your abstract model class might have  create, update, delete, ... which normally calls mysql db actions. extend your model to create RestModel, which will override and call REST update, delete, put or save.

Comment: I understand, but really you need a Model for this, or I can do as it is in the first instance, use the REST into controllers? :) Thanks again @sabkaraja

Comment: As I said earlier - to use a Model or not is upto you. Whatever works. As coding practice - abstraction would help you in the long run.